# Downgrading kernel 4.8.0 to 4.4

Tags: 16.04, kernel, 16.10, downgrade

I want to downgrade my kernel to 4.8 to 4.4. Does anyone know how to downgrade kernel? I have a 64 bit system.

If you are wondering, some of my systems aren't compatible with kernel 4.8.
I tried to google about it, but no hope.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 16.10 right now. I want ubuntu 16.04 version of kernel

Comment: Why not use 16.04?

Comment: I don't know how to downgrade 16.10 to 16.04...

Comment: There is no way to downgrade. You need to do a fresh install.

Comment: Does that mean I need to delete the entire system and get a new .iso image?

Comment: You do not need to delete anything. You can get a 16.04 iso and do a fresh install from it.

Comment: Sorry for noobish question, but how do i do it?

Comment: How do you do what? Install Ubuntu or get an iso? The same way you previously installed Ubuntu.

Comment: No I meant like how do I delete the current OS, so that I can grab a new iso and plug it in

Comment: You do not need to delete the current OS. Boot from LiveUSB and you will have an option to replace the current OS with the other one.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 4.4 kernel is not supported in Ubuntu 16.10.

You can use Ubuntu 16.04 on hardware that you claim to be incompatible with the 4.8 kernel.

Comment: Can I use kernel 4.6 instead?

Comment: You can use any kernel you like, but the only supported kernel on 16.10 is 4.8.

Comment: @goddamit: you can use any kernel you like, but custom kernel questions are off-topic here... Also, if the answer helped you, don't forget to [accept it](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)